# django i18n_urlpatterns not activate new language

Tags: django, url, internationalization, multilingual, reverse

I have this languages in my settings.py on django:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'    
LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', 'English'),
        ('de', 'Deutsch'),
        ('es', 'Spanish'),
    )
```

in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name="admin"),
)

casas_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', totes_cases ,name="all_houses"),
    url(r'^(?P<Propietat_id>\d+).html$', fitxa_casa, name='fitxa_casa'),

)
urlpatterns+=i18n_patterns('',
    url(_(r'^propiedades/'), include(casas_patterns, namespace='casas')),
)
```

and in my template:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_available_languages as languages %}

{% trans "View this category in:" %}
{% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}
    {% language lang_code %}
    <a href="{% url 'casas:all_houses' %}">{{ lang_code }}</a>
    {% endlanguage %}
{% endfor %}
```

It generates me this 3 urls:

/en/propiedades/

/de/propiedades/

/es/propiedades/

But the only one working is the spanish one (es/propiedades/), the other ones are throwing a 404 error like this.

```
Using the URLconf defined in inmoport.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^hola.html$ [name='hola']
^admin/
^es/
```

Do you know how to auto activate the language when is on the prefix on the URL??
Many thanks!

Comment: Did you include LocaleMiddleware?

Comment: Wow man! That's the trick! Many thanks!! ;)